# Created Excel file using OpenXML needs repair when opened in Excel

Tags: excel, cell, openxml

I am trying to insert Excel file (.xlsx)  cell using C# openXML,

but when I open the created Excel file it is need to be repaired by showing following error,

> Repaired Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part

Here is my code.

```
    public void InsertText(TestModelList data)
    {
        var date_time = DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace("/", "_").Replace(":", "_");
        string OutputFileDirectory = "E:\\TEST";
        string fileFullName = Path.Combine(OutputFileDirectory, "Output.xlsx");
        if (File.Exists(fileFullName))
        {
            fileFullName = Path.Combine(OutputFileDirectory, "Output_" + date_time + ".xlsx");
        }

        using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(fileFullName, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
        {
            WorkbookPart wbp = spreadSheet.AddWorkbookPart();
            WorksheetPart wsp = wbp.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            Workbook wb = new Workbook();
            Worksheet ws = new Worksheet();
            SheetData sd = new SheetData();
            InsertToCell(1, "C", "1C", sd);
            ws.Append(sd);
            wsp.Worksheet = ws;
            wsp.Worksheet.Save();
            Sheets sheets = new Sheets();
            Sheet sheet = new Sheet()
            {
                Id = wbp.GetIdOfPart(wsp),
                Name  = "test",
                SheetId = 1
            };

            sheets.Append(sheet);
            wb.Append(sheets);
            spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook = wb;
            spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
        }
    }

    private void InsertToCell(uint rowIndex, string col, string value, SheetData sd)
    {
        var row = new Row() { RowIndex = rowIndex };

        var cellReference = col + rowIndex;

        Cell newCell = new Cell
        {
            StyleIndex = (UInt32Value)1U,
            CellValue = new CellValue(value),
            DataType = CellValues.SharedString,
            CellReference = cellReference
        };
        row.InsertBefore(newCell, null);
        sd.Append(row);
    }
```

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Does choosing open-and-repair work? If yes, save that result to a new file name, close. Open the original file in the Open XML sDK Productivity Tool. Use the Compare feature on the repaired file. Inspect the code used to create that from the original and compare it to what your code is doing. That should at least narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: Which version of the Open XML SDK do you use?

Comment: OpenXMl v2.10.1

Comment: @Ravihansa, OK, I asked the question because v2.10.0 had an issue that could lead to such error messages. Now, having looked at your code in more detail, I identified a number of issues and provided a solution in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with the new cell that you are creating. Firstly, you are setting the `StyleIndex` property (`ssml:s` attribute) to a value of `1U` without having a `WorkbookStylesPart` that contains a referenceable cell style. Secondly, you are setting the `DataType` property (`ssml:t` attribute) to a value of `CellValues.SharedString` (i.e., `"s"`) without having a `SharedStringTablePart`. The `CellValue` property (`ssml:v` element) should be the zero-based index of the `SharedStringItem` (`ssml:si` element) within the `SharedStringTable` (`ssml:sst` element) instead of `"1C"`.

Here is some sample code in the form of a working unit test that demonstrates how to do what you want to achieve:

```cs
[Fact]
public void CanInsertCell()
{
    using var stream = new MemoryStream();
    using (var spreadsheetDocument =
        SpreadsheetDocument.Create(stream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
    {
        // Create an empty workbook.
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
        workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook(new Sheets());

        // Create an empty worksheet and add the worksheet to the workbook.
        var worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());
        workbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.AppendChild(new Sheet
        {
            Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
            Name = "Test",
            SheetId = 1
        });

        // This example correctly inserts a cell with an inline string,
        // noting that Excel always inserts shared strings as shown in
        // the next example.
        InsertCellWithInlineString(worksheetPart.Worksheet, 1, "C", "1C");

        // This example inserts a cell with a shared string that is
        // contained in the SharedStringTablePart. Note that the cell
        // value is the zero-based index of the SharedStringItem
        // contained in the SharedStringTable.
        var sharedStringTablePart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<SharedStringTablePart>();
        sharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable =
            new SharedStringTable(
                new SharedStringItem(
                    new Text("2C")));

        InsertCellWithSharedString(worksheetPart.Worksheet, 2, "C", 0);
    }

    File.WriteAllBytes("WorkbookWithNewCells.xlsx", stream.ToArray());
}

private static void InsertCellWithInlineString(
    Worksheet worksheet,
    uint rowIndex,
    string columnName,
    string value)
{
    InsertCell(worksheet, rowIndex, new Cell
    {
        CellReference = columnName + rowIndex,
        DataType = CellValues.InlineString,
        InlineString = new InlineString(new Text(value)),
    });
}

private static void InsertCellWithSharedString(
    Worksheet worksheet,
    uint rowIndex,
    string columnName,
    uint value)

{
    InsertCell(worksheet, rowIndex, new Cell
    {
        CellReference = columnName + rowIndex,
        DataType = CellValues.SharedString,
        CellValue = new CellValue(value.ToString())
    });
}

private static void InsertCell(Worksheet worksheet, uint rowIndex, Cell cell)
{
    SheetData sheetData = worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().Single();

    // Get or create a Row with the given rowIndex.
    Row row = sheetData.Elements<Row>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex);
    if (row == null)
    {
        row = new Row { RowIndex = rowIndex };

        // The sample assumes that the newRow can simply be appended,
        // e.g., because rows are added in ascending order only.
        sheetData.AppendChild(row);
    }

    // The sample assumes two things: First, no cell with the same cell
    // reference exists. Second, cells are added in ascending order.
    // If that is not the case, you need to deal with that situation.
    row.AppendChild(cell);
}
```